# Wait until multiple request to be executed and their completion block

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, grand-central-dispatch, nsurlrequest

Consider a scenario, I have a function "REFRESH", this function is called by different methods simultaneously, let's say the methods are "A", "B", "C". If method "A" calls "REFRESH TOKEN" firstly then methods "B" and "C" should wait until it finishes.

How can I attain this scenario? Appreciate your help!

```
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "serialQueue")
var myFlag = false


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.refresh(param: 1) // Method A
    self.refresh(param: 2) // Method B
    self.refresh(param: 3) // Method C

}

// Method REFRESH

func refresh(param: NSInteger) -> Void {

let absolutePath = "MY SAMPLE API"
var headers: [String: String] = Dictionary<String, String>();
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"


serialQueue.sync {
    print("\nEntered ", param)
Alamofire.request(absolutePath, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseString {
    response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        print("SUCCESS")
        break
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }

}
```

Above code output:

```
Entered  1
Entered  2
Entered  3
SUCCESS
SUCCESS
SUCCESS
```

I need an output like this:

```
Entered  1
SUCCESS
Entered  2
SUCCESS
Entered  3
SUCCESS
```

Comment: Do you need any dependency between these calls? Like, do you need anything you got from the call to **A** when you call **B**? Or they just need to be executed in an ordered/serial fashion?

Comment: Not related each other. My exact use case is:
Consider in a view controller I'm making 3 network calls parallel during the time when JWT token has expired. In this scenario, whats happening is all 3 calls are requested and for each call refresh token API is called. How to avoid calling refresh API call 3 times and perform it only once per any number of calls in that scenario

Comment: Oh, well. If that's the case, you don't need to consider any dependency at all. You could just use a `Bool` like `refreshCalled` which is initially set to `false`. Then check the status of that boolean with an `if` condition in the **refresh** function, if not called previously, execute the function. And also update the boolean to `true` inside the `if` condition as the first statement.

Comment: I need to retry those failed API's. So I'm planning to synchronize the refresh token function so all other API's should wait until it finishes

please refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49252821/how-to-handle-session-in-rxswift-using-rxalamofirerefresh-token

Comment: Actually, I'm not familiar with **RxSwift**. But I tried to answer this question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is something called ***resource locking***. You can achieve this by using `DispatchGroup`.

First you need to create a `DispatchGroup`. Add a property in your controller:

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
```

Then modify your `refresh(param:)` function as: (I've modified some of the coding patterns)

```
func refresh(param: NSInteger) -> Void {
    // You lock your resource by entering to the dispatch group
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    let absolutePath = "MY SAMPLE API"
    var headers = [String: String]()
    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
    print("Entered \(param)")
    Alamofire.request(absolutePath, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseString { [weak self] (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print("SUCCESS \(param)")
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
        // You release the resource as soon as you get the response so that other processes may be able to use the resource
        self?.dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
    // The lock continues by invoking the wait method
    dispatchGroup.wait()
}
```

So, this will work as:

`Method 1` & `Method 2` are requesting to use the same resource. When `Method 1` is executing, `Method 2` will wait for Method 1 to finish. When `Method 1` is finished, `Method 2` will be given the opportunity to start it's execution.

***So, basically which method first starts executing will finish and then the other will be started***. Though it's not guaranteed which will start the execution first (As, you don't need dependency on each other). But it will depend on the sequence you invoke this method.

Comment: To achieve this kind of simple task, the usage of semaphore isn't a good idea. It's just _kill a fly with a cannon_.

Comment: my actual use case is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49252821/how-to-handle-session-in-rxswift-using-rxalamofirerefresh-token

Answer (score 2):

```
func refresh(param: NSInteger, completion: (Void) -> ()) -> Void {
let absolutePath = "MY SAMPLE API"
var headers: [String: String] = Dictionary<String, String>();
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"


    print("\nEntered ", param)
    Alamofire.request(absolutePath, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseString {
        response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            completion()
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            completion()
        }
}
}

  //In viewDidLoad :- Add these below code

   // Create one custom queue.
   let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "serialQueue")

   // Create one dispacth group.
  let dispatchGorup = DispatchGroup()

 //Call first refresh method with respective parameters.
 dispatchGorup.enter()
  //Wait for the response and then call leave method.
   refresh(param: "") { (result) in
   dispatchGorup.leave()
   }

 //Call second refresh method with respective parameters.
dispatchGorup.enter()
  //Wait for the response and then call leave method.
  refresh(param: "") { (result) in
  dispatchGorup.leave()
 }

//Indication that all the request is done.
dispatchGorup.notify(queue: serialQueue) {
   Print("All methods invoked")
 }
```

Comment: I believe this does not solve the OP's problem, plus some explanation would be fine..

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var param:[Int] = [1,2,3]

func refresh(){ 

    DispatchQueue.global().async {

        for i in 0..<param.count{

            let group = DispatchGroup()
            group.enter()
            print("\nEntered ", param[i])

            let absolutePath = "MY SAMPLE API"
            var headers: [String: String] = Dictionary<String, String>();
            headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

            Alamofire.request(absolutePath, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseString {
    response in
                switch response.result {
                    case .success:
                        print("SUCCESS")
                        break
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                }

                group.leave()

            }

            group.wait()

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your request, I would say that you want a serialized calling of those `refresh` calls. That means that you have to wait until one call ends to call next.

Simple, but a bit ugly solution is to use completion closure:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.refresh(param: 1, completion: { [weak self] in
        self?.refresh(param: 2, completion: { [weak self] in
            self?.refresh(param: 3, completion: nil)
        })
    })
}

// Method REFRESH

func refresh(param: NSInteger, completion: (() -> Void)?) -> Void {

    let absolutePath = "MY SAMPLE API"
    var headers: [String: String] = Dictionary<String, String>();
    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

    print("\nEntered ", param)
    Alamofire.request(absolutePath, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseString {
        response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print("SUCCESS")
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
        completion?()
    }
}
```

Based on what you say in your comment (that you just want to get refresh token from the first call and then it does not matter) you can rewrite `viewDidLoad` it as this:

```
self.refresh(param: 1, completion: { [weak self] in
    // these two can now go in parallel, since the first call got you the refresh token
    self?.refresh(param: 2, completion: nil)
    self?.refresh(param: 3, completion: nil)
})
```